# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sep_labels'

Tags: python, sh, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run the code of a paper, available at the following repository: https://github.com/renmengye/rec-attend-public
However, I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup_cvppp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from data_api.cvppp import CVPPPAssembler
  File "/home/lmancuso/leaf/rec-attend-public/data_api/cvppp.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sep_labels
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sep_labels'
```

I do not know why, because the sep_labels.py is in the same folder of cvppp.py. So, this is cvppp.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import sep_labels

from ins_seg_dataset import InsSegDataset
from ins_seg_assembler import InsSegAssembler
from tqdm import tqdm


class CVPPPAssembler(InsSegAssembler):

  def __init__(self, folder, opt, split=None, output_fname=None):
    self.folder = folder
    self.split = split
    self.label_regex = re.compile('plant(?P<imgid>[0-9]{3})_label.png')
    self.image_regex = re.compile('plant(?P<imgid>[0-9]{3})_rgb.png')
    self.fg_regex = re.compile('plant(?P<imgid>[0-9]{3})_fg.png')
    if output_fname is None:
      output_fname = os.path.join(folder, '{}_{}x{}.h5'.format(
          split, opt['height'], opt['width']))
    super(CVPPPAssembler, self).__init__(opt, output_fname)

    ...
```

and this is sep_labels.py, which is located in the same folder of cvppp.py

```
import numpy as np

def get_separate_labels(label_img):
    # 64-bit encoding
    dtype = label_img.dtype
    if dtype == np.uint8:
        w = 8
    elif dtype == np.uint16:
        w = 16
    else:
        raise Exception('Unknown dtype: "{}"'.format(dtype))
    l64 = label_img.astype('uint64')
    # Single channel mapping
    if len(l64.shape) == 3:
        l64i = ((l64[:, :, 0] << 2 * w) + (l64[:, :, 1] << w) + l64[:, :, 2])
    else:
        l64i = l64
    colors = np.unique(l64i)
    segmentations = []
    colors_all = []
    for c in colors:
        if c != 0:
            segmentation = (l64i == c).astype('uint8')
            segmentations.append(segmentation)
            colors_all.append(c)
    return segmentations, colors_all
```

Comment: Sometimes, when running projects on IDE (mostly for me this happens on Pycharm) you have to say which directory is the source dir, so the imports know where they are being based off.

Comment: @Arson0 I am using the terminal